# Adding to a list copies the instance of a class?

Tags: c#, list

As far as I read up on lists and classes, if you have a list of instances of a certain class and .Add() them to a list, the reference should be added. So if you modify the original instance, and then access it via the list, you should get the modified version.

Here is the structure of my code:

```
public class Config()
{
    public List<Item> listOfItems = new List<Item>();
    public Item item1 = new Item();
    public Item item2 = new Item();

    ...
    Config()
    {
        listOfItems.Add(item1);
        listOfItems.Add(item2);
        ...
    }
}

public class Item
{ 
    public string name;

    Item()
    { 
        name = "Not Set";
        ...
    }
}
```

and somewhere in my main code I'd use currentConfig, which is an instance of the Config class:

```
currentConfig.item1.name = "A";
currentConfig.item2.name = "B";

for (int i = 0; i < currentConfig.listOfItems.Count; i++)
{ 
    DoSomething(currentConfig.listOfItems[i].name);
}
```

But that does not give me the current value of item1.name and item2.name, but rather "Not set". What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you initialize your `listOfItems`? Are there `get/set` method in Item class?

Comment: You don't ever set name to anything else. Is code missing?

Comment: Where do you set different names to item1 and item2?

Comment: `List`s do not create copies of reference objects. The mistake is somewhere else in your code.

Comment: @sarwar026 listOfItems is not modified in any other way than creating it, and the .Add in the constructor of the Config class. Atm I don't use set/get, but it makes no differences whether I do (just tried it).

Comment: @usr Added the changing of the name to the code example, they are set somewhere before the for-loop.

Comment: Change DoSomething to Console.WriteLine. If this is all code that is running you will see A,B printed.

Comment: @usr still "Not Set". There is a lot of code happening, but nothing with the list or the existence of currentConfig itself. Anything else that could provoke that behavior?

Comment: "but nothing with the list or the existence of currentConfig itself" this is most likely untrue. You just don't see it. The code as shown is correct and the repro answers prove it. The mistake is elsewhere. Nothing mysterious is going on here, there is just a bug somewhere. List does not clone and c# has reference semantics. Simplify your code by commenting out stuff until it happens to work. Then you know where the problem is. You can use object.GetHashCode to differentiate between different object instances in the debugger, btw.

Comment: @Epikur how many lines of code have you snipped out? If you can provide your complete code here or in a Gist/Pastebin (or similar) maybe someone can spot the issue you're having. The code you've included doesn't generate the behaviour your seeing...

Answer (score 1):

I can't replicate your problem...

If I run the below it demonstrates that the items are A and B as expected

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class Stack1
    {
        [Test]
        public void TestConfigItems()
        {
            var currentConfig = new Config();

            currentConfig.item1.name = "A";
            currentConfig.item2.name = "B";

            for (int i = 0; i < currentConfig.listOfItems.Count; i++)
            {
                Assert.AreNotEqual("Not Set", currentConfig.listOfItems[i].name);
                Assert.AreEqual(i == 0 ? "A" : "B", currentConfig.listOfItems[i].name);
            }
        }

        public class Config
        {
            public List<Item> listOfItems = new List<Item>();
            public Item item1 = new Item();
            public Item item2 = new Item();

            public Config()
            {
                listOfItems.Add(item1);
                listOfItems.Add(item2);
            }
        }

        public class Item
        { 
            public string name;

            public Item()
            { 
                name = "Not Set";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I re-wrote your code and I didn't see what you saw. Everything is ok and `name` property changed correctly.
This is what I've done:

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var currentConfig = new Config();
        currentConfig.item1.name = "A";
        currentConfig.item2.name = "B";

        for (var i = 0; i < currentConfig.listOfItems.Count; i++)
            Console.WriteLine(currentConfig.listOfItems[i].name);
    }
}

public class Config
{
    public Item item1 = new Item();
    public Item item2 = new Item();
    public List<Item> listOfItems = new List<Item>();

    public Config()
    {
        this.listOfItems.Add(this.item1);
        this.listOfItems.Add(this.item2);
    }
}

public class Item
{
    public string name;

    public Item()
    {
        this.name = "Not Set";
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain shortly why you used "this" in this.listOfItems.Add(this.item1), and should it make any difference?

Comment: @Epikur 'this' refers to the instance of the class. It isn't necessary to add it but some people prefer to use it for clarity. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk1507sz.aspx